# Is it ok to register my apple iphone (as ad hoc provisioning profile) on my customers apple developer account for testing?

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-developer

I'm developing an expo managed react native app specialy for ios and it contain native modules so I'm creating development builds to test. And I don't have an apple computer or an apple developer membership. My customer has an apple developer account with membership so can I register my iphone in his account to test the development build and will I be able to remove my device from his account after testing? what is the best solution?